# Bash: "command not found" on simple variable assignment

Tags: bash

Here's a simple version of my script which displays the failure:

```
#!/bin/bash
${something:="false"}
${something_else:="blahblah"}
${name:="file.ext"}

echo ${something}
echo ${something_else}
echo ${name}
```

When I echo the variables, I get the values I put in, but it also emits an error. What am I doing wrong?

Output:

```
./test.sh: line 3: blahblah: command not found
./test.sh: line 4: file.ext: command not found
false
blahblah
file.ext
```

The first two lines are being emitted to stderr, while the next three are being output to stdout.

My platform is fedora 15, bash version 4.2.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a variable on a line by itself will execute the command stored in the variable. That an assignment is being performed at the same time is incidental.

In short, don't do that.

```
echo ${something:="false"}
echo ${something_else:="blahblah"}
echo ${name:="file.ext"}
```

Comment: Hmph, I don't know why I didn't realize that... I guess that solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can add colon:

```
: ${something:="false"}
: ${something_else:="blahblah"}
: ${name:="file.ext"}
```

The trick with a ":" (no-operation command) is that, nothing gets executated, but parameters gets expanded. Personally I don't like this syntax, because for people not knowing this trick the code is difficult to understand.

You can use this as an alternative:

```
something=${something:-"default value"}
```

or longer, more portable (but IMHO more readable):

```
[ "$something" ] || something="default value"
```

Comment: Huh, I did a quick `man :` and I think the : will do what I like. I'll make sure to comment this thoroughly though. Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: the ":" is a builtin. You need to "help :" or "man bash". See "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" section.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply

```
variable_name=value
```

If you use `$(variable_name:=value}` bash substitutes the variable_name if it is set otherwise it uses the default you specified.

Comment: That was the point. Sorry about not specifying that in the question.